# Core Data: NSManagedObjectContext's save() method takes more than a minute to save an object with unique constraints

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, unique-constraint

I am having there entities `ChatMessage`, `ChatUser` and `ChatRoom`.

```
class ChatMessage: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String // Unique constraint
    @NSManaged var message: String

    @NSManaged var user: ChatUser
    @NSManaged var room: ChatRoom
}

class ChatUser: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String // Unique constraint
    @NSManaged var name: String

    @NSManaged var messages: Set<ChatMessage>
}

class ChatRoom: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String // Unique constraint
    @NSManaged var name: String

    @NSManaged var messages: Set<ChatMessage>
}
```

Let's say there are 100 `ChatUser`s with 100 `ChatRoom`s and each contains at least 5000 `ChatMessage`s.

The ChatServer works with the sync policy that it can deliver duplicate ChatMessages but it should not miss even a single one. Therefore the iOS client should check for duplicates. But fortunately `Core Data` facilitates `unique key constraints` and it takes care of the duplicate issue without any additional programming effort.

But which takes more than a minute to save a new `ChatMessage` and `Xcode` instruments shows that `isEquals:` method from `NSString` takes more time. The reason is, `Core Data` checks for uniqueness during the save().

If I remove the `id` unique constraint everything works fine but I need to handle duplicates with extra code effort.

What is my mistake here? or is it a Core Data issue? I am spending some days to find out the problem. What would be the correct way to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your doing this wrongly, you set a constraint on a table and then you deliberately violate that constraint, a constraint is not a filtering tool in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ChatUser.messages property is a set and a set only contains unique values you should be able to make use of that by adding all messages to the user object and the room object they belong to and get any duplicates removed for free.

Comment: The question is not about the behaviors of a `Set`rather about `Advanced Core Data`. Please read the question carefully before you answer and please (please * 1000) don't mislead other readers by your comments and answers.

Comment: @Goppinath What is that supposed to mean, mislead? I tried to help by giving an alternative where the uniqueness requirement was handled before saving. Your question is very vague so it is impossible to give an exact answer.